# Create ParseFile with base64-encoded String in Android

Tags: android, parse-platform

Is it possible to create a ParseFile with base64-encoded String with Parse Android SDK?. Documentation only speaks about data in byte[] form.

JavaScript Guide shows a way to deal with Base64.

```
var file = new Parse.File("myfile.txt", { base64: base64 });
```

Is something similar possible in Android?

Comment: Is this the same as the ParseFile specified in these docs http://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseFile.html ?

Answer (score 1):

I've never used Parse.com before, but from the [doc](https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#files-the-parsefile) you can use the [`ParseFile`](http://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseFile.html#ParseFile(java.io.File,%20java.lang.String)) constructor that accepts a `File` and a `String` object.

Moreover you can use the [`Base64`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html) class to perform encoding/decoding.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `android.util.Base64`:

```
ParseFile f = new ParseFile("myfile.txt", Base64.decode(base64data, Base64.DEFAULT));
```

Comment: ughhh my bad, sorry for bothering

Answer (score 0):

There is in built function in `parse.com` for encoding and decoing

```
File file = new File("myfile.txt");
byte[] arrBytes = new byte[(int)file.length()];
byte[] encoded = com.parse.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64(arrBytes);
ParseFile parseFile = new ParseFile(encoded);
```

Comment: The thing is that I start with byte[] data. But in addition to my (encrypted) binary data I need to store information for decryption. So I want to encode all of my binary data, chain everything together and store it as one Base64-encoded String. But encoding my binaray data to Base64 and then back to binary makes no much sense to me. I have to think about another way to store my data. But that's out of the scope of this question.

Comment: couldn't get what do you want.!